Ubuntu 24.04 loses session after sleep/lock
Recently I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 24.04 on my Lenovo X1 Carbon gen 8. Before I had dual boot Ubuntu 23.10 and Win 10 but now I wiped the whole disk and did a clean Ubuntu only install. By setting everything to default settings (not doing anything custom), except enabling disk encryption.
When I leave my laptop for a while (eg. for lunch), when I return, it is in sleep mode and when I wake it up, after I login, all my opened windows are closed. It seems that my session has been lost completely, just like when I logout. I didn't have these issues before on 23.10. This is driving me crazy so I must solve it ASAP.
A few possibly related facts:

it's a dual GPU laptop (Intel onboard + nVidia)
I don't have nVidia drivers installed
I did click to install third-party drivers during install
my disk is encrypted
I don't have swap partition - I was told that Ubuntu now by default uses swap file so I just left default settings to use swap file
sleep settings in BIOS are already set to "Linux" mode
I'm using built-in display + external 24" display connected through HDMI
fun fact: my external display is set as main display, which means that when I turn my laptop on, the login screen will appear on main monitor but after this sleep-logout event happens, login display will appear on the laptop's screen and like this I immediately know that I've lost the session but as soon as I log-in back, everything is back to normal - my external screen becomes main one and all the settings (position, resolution, scale) are preserved
the only other peripheral is a Bluetooth mouse and TP Link USB-Ethernet dongle
the laptop is plugged-in 99% of the time
might not be related but occasionally it happens that, when I turn on the laptop, audio doesn't work - it just says "Dummy Output" and I have to reboot it again to make it work
might not be related but some of my manually added startup applications won't start every time I start the laptop, just occasionally

My questions and thoughts:

could it be that there's a setting to auto-logout in case of inactivity?
should I install nVidia drivers? I don't need the nVidia GPU
am I missing some other drivers?
are there any logs I can check AFTER this happens and when I log-in back?


Your question makes no mention of the Power Settings in the OS. Take a look there and adjust as needed.

@David can you be more precise? I'm switching between all the power settings as needed, but mostly using Max performance while on power, and Power saving when on battery. But nowhere I see the mention of "auto-logout". And no, I'm not planning to disable suspend, I often use suspend mode so my goal is to fix that it's not losing session when I use suspend so it's actually good for me that it automatically suspends or locks the screen during inactivity, but I want to be able to simply wake it up from sleep, log-in and continue where I left so it must not lose session on suspend.

Please edit the question and add the fact you have edited some of the power settings. Look at screen time outs as well. You can try turning off suspend for now to see what effect that has.

I'm not sure how this solves my issue? Disabling suspend is not an option! Suspend must work as I'm using it, this is one of the basic features of any OS. So I need to fix the bug which causes lost session on suspend, not disable suspend entirely. I also don't understand how screen timeouts are related? Yes, I want my screen to turn off because of inactivity and I want my laptop to go to sleep, but no, I don't want to lose my session. So the topic is how to prevent losing session, not anything else.

If you are not willing to troubleshoot there is nothing anyone can do to help you. I never said leave it off.

I was hoping there's a setting, or a known bug or a way to check logs and find out the actual problem. That's why I asked instead of debugging myself. This machine is causing me headaches since I did clean install. I solved 5 problems, got 20 new ones and it's really now critical with time because I need to focus on my work now because I'm faaar behind with deadlines and I don't have much time to debug. I turned auto-sleep and auto-lock off for now to avoid the problem. I can troubleshoot but I need some concrete steps.

I have the same problem. And even just turning off/on monitor cause this issue.
I have Ubuntu 24.04 with a Dell monitor. It is really annoying. I have to lock the user without shutting off the monitor otherwise I loose all my changes
But try to enable Wayland and see if you have the same problem. I've just enabled it instead of using X11 and it seems to fix the problem

I'm using Wayland already, I even used it on older Ubuntu versions because it has better Bluetooth support and gives me the ability to choose different profiles so my Samsung Galaxy Buds 2 sound better, without distortion. I haven't seen the issue in a while but yet again, I disabled any kind of auto-sleep/auto-lock mechanisms and I keep my machine on all the time.

I had already removed any sleep mechanism in the past but before changing x11 to wayland I always had that problem. Just switching to wayland (with same other changes) fix the problem. And the laptop with intel/radeon cards (with same ubuntu version) where wayland was installed by default didn't had that problem.
